# Using extentreports for jmeter test results

Tags: jmeter

As anyone who uses jmeter for api functional testing, the reporting is, eh, not that great.  Has anyone used something like http://extentreports.com/ for displaying their test results?  Any ideas on other ways to display test results better?  In trying to use a tool that was mainly focused on performance testing and those test results, that does not work as well for when we are testing REST API calls and those results.  For example, it would be nice to be able to capture data that is getting created during the test runs but, none of the reports that are built into jmeter do this.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Here is the best way of generating report dashboard http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looking into [Extent - Report API](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/) it should be possible to integrate it with JMeter, see [How to Write a plugin for JMeter guide to get started](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf)
2. You can generate an [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) at the end of your test run, it is not that bad.
3. You can use [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) to store JMeter test results somewhere and visualise them in the most suitable for your form. See [Real-time results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) JMeter User Manual chapter for more details.
4. And last but not least you can use 3rd-party analysis services like [JAnalyzer](http://epireum.com/page-section/janalyser/) or [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the multiple options Dmitri.  Options 1 and 3 are looking good.  For #1, I have never written a plugin. Do I really need one? Couldn't I just save the extentreports jar into the lib folder and start calling it's functions by using 'import' in a bean pre/post processor?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use extentreports 2.41.1 and posted this code into a JSR223 PreProcessor.  This seems to be the wrong element to put this in because I need results for each endpoint to show up in the report.  This only just shows the script ran.  Anyway, sharing in hopes it helps others

```
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

ExtentReports report;
ExtentTest testLogger;

String resultsPath = "C:/portalQA/Automation/Results";
String configPath = "C:/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.2/lib";
String reportPath;

reportPath = resultsPath+"/test2/testing_extRpts_${myTimeinMills}.html";

report = new ExtentReports(reportPath, true);
report.loadConfig( new File(configPath+"extent-config.xml"));

testLogger = report.startTest("Entire Script");
testLogger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "This is the API test script for Login");

report.flush();
//Thread.sleep(2000);
//report.close();
```