# Jmeter - Functional Extent Report

Tags: jmeter, extent

I would like to use Extent Report in Jmeter for functional testing. Please suggest some sample script and language, library to do this. I explored our page and unable to get the lib and steps to implement them.

I followed the [Using extentreports for jmeter test results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946292/using-extentreports-for-jmeter-test-results?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
However, I am getting error message

> Typed variable declaration : Class: ExtentReports not found in namespace

I am using extentreports-3.1.2.jar and kept inside the Jmeter Lib folder. Also I have imported them in the script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at Extents reports documentation? It seems to be comprehensive enough.

I don't know what you mean by "use Extent Report in Jmeter for functional testing", but given you're asking for a sampler code here is a minimal snippet suitable for using in any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) assuming [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the language:

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ViewStyle

def extentReports = new ExtentReports()
def reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter("report", ViewStyle.SPA)

extentReports.attachReporter(reporter)

def firstTest = extentReports.createTest("SomeTest")
firstTest.log(Status.PASS, 'Everything ok')

extentReports.flush()
```

You will need to:

1. Have [extentreports-4.1.7.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/aventstack/extentreports/4.1.7/extentreports-4.1.7.jar) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (as well as all it's [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) if you will be using MongoDB as the reporting backend)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response. I checked the document. I kept extentreports-5.0.9.jar inside Lib folder and used JSR223 Element. I used Java as the language. I am getting the below message "Error in method invocation: Method AttachReporter( com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter ) not found in class'com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports'". It is throwing at line "extent.AttachReporter(spark);"

Comment: You're neither using the same library version nor the same code, what do you want from me exactly?